# All commands that create files in /etc error with "Invalid argument"

Tags: linux

I recently developed a problem on some embedded linux devices where I can no longer create files directly in the /etc/ directory. I first saw the problem when dpkg failed to create a temporary file, and then "sed -i" had the same problem. I have since tried touch, cp, and redirected echoes, but they all fail with Invalid argument.

I running strace on "cp /etc/hostname /etc/hostname.bak" yields the following output,

```
stat64("/etc/hostname.bak", 0xbede4560) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/etc/hostname", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12, ...}) = 0
stat64("/etc/hostname.bak", 0xbede4398) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/hostname", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/hostname.bak", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0644) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "cp: ", 4cp: )                     = 4
write(2, "cannot create regular file `/etc"..., 46cannot create regular file `/etc/hostname.bak') = 46
write(2, ": Invalid argument", 18: Invalid argument)      = 18
```

while running strace on "cp /etc/hostname /hostname.bak" yields

```
stat64("/hostname.bak", 0xbec75570)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/etc/hostname", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12, ...}) = 0
stat64("/hostname.bak", 0xbec753a8)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/hostname", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12, ...}) = 0
open("/hostname.bak", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0644) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

Once the file /hostname.bak exists I can then move it into /etc/ without incident.

The permissions on /etc/ seem right to me as well

```
drwxr-xr-x 75 root root   36864 Mar 29 00:08 etc
```

Is there any kind of setting or configuration could cause this behavior? If not how could I go about debugging

Comment: I haven't figured out the root cause of this behavior, but I found out an application was remounting the file system rw (default is ro) to create a file in /etc early on in the boot process. Delaying that process seemed to fix the problem for me. My guess is a bug in my older version of the kernel.